# Boundary Summation Problems

Tags: boundary-value-problem

I am taking Algorithm and DS class this semster and the first questiom on the homework was to find the tight bounds of a series. I have never studied boundary summation problems  and don't know how to solve such problems. Can someone cite me some sources to learn it. I checked online but none of them were beginner friendly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get a copy of the syllabus for the course and look at the references in there.

Comment: I checked the syllabus and it doesn't list any. The book does jave an appendix for such problems but it covers the topic in like half a page, so not helpful.